# Are "as follows" and " "the following" the same in the following sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

> Are the specifications of the product (the following/as follows)?

In this sentence, is it okay to use 'the following' instead of 'as follows'?

Comment: Yes. The sentence is a bit odd, but it is idiomatic.

Comment: Okay! Thank you!